# Install poetry in specific folder / partition on Windows 10

Tags: python-poetry

I want to install poetry on my data partition (D:) under Windows 10 Pro.

I know how to [install poetry on Windows](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#:%7E:text=The%20installer%20installs%20the%20poetry,poetry%5Cbin%20.)

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py -UseBasicParsing).Content | python -
```

The same page specifies that I can chose a custom install directory by setting a system variable

```
POETRY_HOME=/etc/poetry python get-poetry.py
```

However the first command I'm using is a Powershell command. The second command rather looks like a bash command.

How to combine the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just found out that I just can create a user variable the "usual way":

Settings -> "Edit the system environment variables" -> Environment Variables -> User Variable -> New

```
Name: POETRY_HOME
Value: D:\path\to\my\poetry
```

then run the installation command shown above. It will pick up the correct installation path